# How can I replace tags in multiple files at once if each one has unique number values?

Tags: html, regex, xml, svg

I have 70+ SVG files that I want to modify in bulk.

They all start with this tag:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 78.51 112.15">
```

But I want to convert that to this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 78.51 112.15" width="78.51" height="112.15">
```

*Each file has different width/height values.*

I'm guessing that there's some way to do this with Regex and Notepad++, but I have no idea how. Seems like I would need to pass the width and height as variables somehow?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You could write an xslt transform.

Comment: In notepad++ you might use a pattern like `<svg [^<>]*viewBox="\d+(?:\.\d+)? \d+(?:\.\d+)? \K((\d+(?:\.\d+)?) (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)")([^<>]*>)` and replace with `$1 width="$2" height="$3"$4` https://regex101.com/r/h8rWwV/1/ but parsing html/xml like structures is better done with a parser.

Answer (score 0):

From @TheFourthBird:

> In notepad++ you might use a pattern like ]*viewBox="\d+(?:.\d+)? \d+(?:.\d+)? \K((\d+(?:.\d+)?) (\d+(?:.\d+)?)")([^<>]*>) and replace with $1 width="$2" height="$3"$4 regex101.com/r/h8rWwV/1 but parsing html/xml like structures is better done with a parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Find what: `0 0 \K(\d+\.\d+ )(\d+\.\d+")`
Replace with: `$1$2 width="$1height="$2`

Uncheck `match-case`